# Show Button(s) only at a specific date

Tags: javascript, html

Good day everyone,

I wanted to develop an advent Calendar webpage, where the doors (1-24) only appear on the designated days.
For example:
On december 1st, there should only be one door visible
On december 15th, there should be doors 1-15 visible,
so that every day another door appears.

I already figured out how to compare the dates to only trigger if it's a match:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test</title>
    <script src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="btn">Hello</button>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```
            var today = new Date();
    var date =  new Date('2022-10-20');
    today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
    date.setHours(0,0,0,0);

    if (+today == +date) {
        console.log("These are the same dates");
        $("#btn").hide();
    } else {
        console.log("These are different dates");
    }
    console.log(today);
    console.log(date);
```

Which returns this in console if it matches:

[image]

And this if it does not match:

[image]

The problem here is, I can't make anything appear, change visibility or enable something.
I tried this:
`document.getElementById("id").style.visibility = 'visible';`, didn't work.
Also made a button with the disabled attribute and tried this:
`button.disabled = false;`, did not work also.
I thought it had something to do with the if-statement, but it doesn't even work outside of it.

Can someone help me?
Thank you guys very much!

Greetings Marcel

Comment: Could you provide the code ?

Comment: It is just a plain html, testing with simple button with id attributes, css and js are linked ofc

Comment: Yes but we can't help you, the code you provided do work, so the issue is in your css or html most likely

Comment: I added the code and implemented the answer from below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the **first date to open the first door**, then you can calculate from there and open doors according to the days since the first day. here is a rework and complete example to clarify that:

```js
var today = new Date();
var firstDay =  new Date('2022/10/25');

today.setHours(0,0,0,0);
firstDay.setHours(0,0,0,0);

let difTime = firstDay.getTime() - today.getTime();

let difDays = difTime  / (1000 * 3600 * 24); // diferent days between the dates

// represent doors
let doors = document.getElementById("container").children;
// array of doors
let allDoors = [...doors];

for (let i = 0; i < difDays; i++) {
    allDoors[i].style.background = "green";  
 }

console.log(difDays);
```

```css
#door {
    padding: 20px 10px;
    background: darkgray;
    border: 1px solid;
    width: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="door"></div>
  <div id="door"></div>
  <div id="door"></div>
  <div id="door"></div>
  <div id="door"></div>
  <div id="door"></div>
  <div id="door"></div>
  <div id="door"></div>
  <div id="door"></div>
  <div id="door"></div>
  <div id="door"></div>
  <div id="door"></div>
  <div id="door"></div>
  <div id="door"></div>
  <div id="door"></div>
  <div id="door"></div>
  <div id="door"></div>
  <div id="door"></div>
  <div id="door"></div>
  <div id="door"></div>
  <div id="door"></div>
  <div id="door"></div>
  <div id="door"></div>
  <div id="door"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I added an if-statement to check whether the number of difDays is positive or negative, so I can prevent the 7th door from opening 7 days before AND 7 days after the firstDay, but only 7 days after.

Comment: As long as you have the first date, you can manage it however you want. glad I helped.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you to use JQuery. In JQuery it's as simple as `$(selector).hide()` or `$(selector).attr('display', 'none')`.
For example: `$("#myBtn").hide()`.

Just don't forget to put `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>` in your `<head></head>`!

Comment: I implemented JQuery, sadly it does not work for me...

Comment: You need the link to the script for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do that simply using JavaScript.

- To hide the button

  document.getElementById("id").style.display = 'none'

in your code

```
document.getElementById("btn").style.display = 'none'
```

- To show the button

  document.getElementById("id").style.display = 'block'

in your code

```
document.getElementById("btn").style.display = 'block'
```

Answer (score 0):

Hide is a jquery funtion to use it you must import jquery and use @xorozo answer
Try to move the script just before the close of body tag